# User profile image not updating

Tags: php, sql-update, user-accounts

On member.php I want the users uploaded profile picture to display.

```
//$profile_data grabs the users data within the database

               <h1><?php echo $profile_data['Name']; ?>'s profile:</h1>

                <?php if (empty($profile_data['profile']) === false) {
                        echo '<img src="',$profile_data['profile'], '" alt="',$profile_data['Name'],'\'sProfile Image">';

                    }
                ?>

                <div class="profile">
                    <?php 
                    if(isset($_FILES['profile']) === true) {
                        if (empty($_FILES['profile'] ['name']) === true)  {
                            echo 'Please choose a file!';
                        }else{
                            $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');

                            $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
                            $file_extn = explode('.', $file_name); 
                            $file_extn = strtolower(end($file_extn));//converts string to lowercase
                            $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

                            if (in_array ($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
                                //upload
                                change_image($MemberID,$file_temp,$file_extn);
                            }else {
                                echo 'Incorrect file type. Allowed: ';
                                echo implode(', ', $allowed);
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    ?>
```

In user.php I have this function:

```
function change_image ($MemberID, $file_temp, $file_extn) {
    $file_path = 'images/profile/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn; //take current time, create md5 hash, 10 character figure 
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
    mysql_query("UPDATE `member` SET `profile` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) . "' WHERE 'MemberID' = " . (int)$MemberID);//update database

    echo "UPDATE `member` SET `profile` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) . "' WHERE `MemberID` = " . (int)$MemberID;
}
```

When I log in as a user and upload an image nothing happens. The database doesn't update but when I echo the query it looks fine, I get:

```
UPDATE `member` SET `profile` = 'images/profile/2d5929413b.jpg' WHERE `MemberID` = 31
```

If i put the query into phpmyadmin it works fine and the file path is there and then the user has an image, but anytime they change their image the query updates but doesn't change the file path in the database.

Really confused, any help please??

Comment: What error do you receive back from MySQL? [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)  Note: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Are you sure that you're actually connected to the database when the query is executed?

Comment: @MrSlayer Thats the thing, I don't get any errors, even when I added mysql_error() there were no errors. I am connected to the database because when I echo the query it pulls out the memberID so I know its connected but when i check the DB the profile field hasn't updated.

Comment: The fact that you get the memberID from a previous connection doesn't mean you still are connected to the database when you try to perform the update query. Please, check the database connection like billyonecan suggested

Comment: @mirtillotta I have included the connection to the DB on each page, just to be sure I tried: echo @mysql_ping() ? 'true' : 'false'; and result was true. Totally lost as to why the file path is not updating in the database :/

Comment: Maybe it's a silly question, but are you also sure that you're referring to the same database that you are checking on with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Same question here: There seems to be a connection, hence no errors, but are you connected to the correct database? Please verify.

Comment: Yes i have checked by DB connection in my include file and it is correct.

Comment: Try to assign the query to a variable and print it out, let's see if some useful information come out:
`$result = mysql_query("UPDATE 'member' SET 'profile' = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) . "' WHERE 'MemberID' = " . (int)$MemberID);
print_r($result);`

Comment: Would you mind replacing the deprecated `mysql_*` statements with the newer `mysqli_*` statements and report back? If this doesn't help, it'll be necessary to provide more code. And btw, what do your logs say?

Comment: If the query runs OK when run through phpMyAdmin, then I would strongly suggest tailing the MySQL logs when you perform the action you mentioned above. You'll then be able to see if the query is indeed being trigged by the request.

Comment: Try checking the result of mysql_query (like was suggested here), then if that's ok try checking the result of mysql_affected_rows() and try doing a `SELECT profile FROM member WHERE memberid = 31` and checking that right from the same script that is doing the update. There will be a clue somewhere here, but if not, then something is updating the profile right after it gets updated here. Good luck!

Comment: OK, thanks for getting back to me everybody! whilst trying some of your suggestions out I was also told to use dots instead of commas to concatenate the image link, remove the (int) and remove commas from MemberID on my query. Dunno why but this has worked. Images are showing up and the file path is now updating in the database. :)

Answer (score 0):

Removed commas and replaced with dots like so:

```
<?php if (empty($profile_data['profile']) === false) {
                        echo '<img src="'.$profile_data['profile']. '" alt="'.$profile_data['Name'].'\'sProfile Image">';
                    echo $profile_data['profile'];
                    }
                ?>
```

Remove INT from query and commas around MemberID:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `member` SET `profile` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) . "' WHERE MemberID = " . $MemberID) ;//update database
```